# When do we say 'an advantage' and 'a plus'

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

Could you tell me about the difference between 'an advantage' and 'a plus'. Are there any differences? Do we use 'an advantage' in formal style?

Comment: _An advantage_ is standard English; _a plus_ is rather colloquial.

Comment: In what context? Please provide a sentence or two. The meanings of the words can be quite different. How are you using them?